# Copying all but last item in a row from csv file to different file

Tags: python, csv, reader, writer

I have a csv with rows of data I need to parse through. I am checking for equality across different lines and sending lines that are the same into their own files. For instance:

```
ABC
ABC
ABC
ACB
ACB
ACB
BCA
BCA
BCA
```

All instances of ABC, ACB, and BCA need to be separated into their own files. That part is easy enough but each row will have a unique file name at the end of it. How can I check each row without the last element of the row?

I'm expecting some way of using `len(row)-1` but not sure where that will fit into the wider syntax.

Edit:

Editing to say you all have been super helpful! row[:-1] was exactly what I needed.

Also I'm new to posting here so if there was a way to set an answer as having solved my issue I've missed it. But thanks to all of you!

Comment: Use `row.pop(-1)` to remove the last element

Comment: Or use `row[:-1]` to select all elements of a row except the last one.

Comment: How are you parsing this CSV and what is your equality test? Isn't it just a case of checking all but the last column? If CSV, looking at `row[:-1]` instead of `row`? If pandas, a table with the last column removed? A minimal example of what you are doing would help.

Comment: last element of the row means: (Which axis are you referring to) last row, or last element in each row? If you can add why you are doing this, it might help.

Comment: *Also I'm new to posting here so if there was a way to set an answer as having solved my issue I've missed it. But thanks to all of you!* -> You can write an answer by yourself and set it as accepted. ;)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, open the file, read the lines as an array, pop the last line, and write the file back somewhere else.

```py
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    rows = f.readlines()
    rows = rows[:-1]
    with open(output_file, 'w') as f2:
       f2.writelines(rows)
```